# How to change font size of axis labels in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm trying to create a dashboard in Tableau desktop but find that axis labels on the bar chart crop and can't find the option to reduce font size. Is it possible wrap axis text as well?

The chart is the penultimate one on this image.

[image]

Comment: Just right click the names and click format

Comment: Clicked but no response. But thank you.

Comment: try opening the sheet where you have developed these bar charts and then  right click the names and click format